# How can I incorporate a C project in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a project, written in C which I want to use in Xamarin Forms. What is the best way to use this code? Generate libraries for each platform?

What I'd prefer is to have one wrapper that I can use in shared code that doesn't have to be implemented for each platform.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, the way binding works is different for Android and iOS, so you would need to generate libraries for each platform.

You can read more about how that is done [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/advanced_topics/native_interop/) for iOS and [here](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/advanced_topics/using_native_libraries/) for Android. For iOS, you can consider using [Objective Sharpie](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/macios/binding/objective-sharpie/) which will do the most of the work for you.

Afterwards, you can simply use [DependecyService](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/dependency-service/introduction/) to access the native platform features.